# MVC 4 querystring value with period

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am implementing OAuth2 into my MVC project.
At the moment I am working with Google Api. The first step worked fine and my callback URL is being called with a parameter code which looks like this:

```
code=4/O89-dMqK-MHn8ynzsEawrpYPL80Y.Mu61gsIzfDMYOl05ti8ZT3adNQ17fgI
```

the problem is that MVC is ignoring it because of the period (.) in the value. I need to know what I can do to get it to work.
If I remove the period, then everything works as it should but I have no control over what google send back to me but I need to be able to read it.

I have tried adding a custom route looking like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*robotstxt}", new { robotstxt = @"(.*/)?robots.txt(/.*)?" });

    // default MVC route
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    ).RouteHandler = new CmsRouteHandler();

    // OAuth route
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "OAuth",
        url: "OAuth/OAuth2Callback*"
    );

    // CatchAll route
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Catchall", // Route name
        "{*url}"
    ).RouteHandler = new CmsRouteHandler();
}
```

but it doesn't appear to work :(

Cheers,
/r3plica

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4.0, add this to `system.web` section of your web.config file

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

It should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Probably this setting should fix it:
`<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>`

Comment: also have this :) does not fix the issue